# (SQL) How to select all fields from table 1 except the id's from table 2?

Tags: sql

I got 3 tables.

```
Users:
id__| login__
--------------
_1__| root
_2__| admin
_3__| user

Table 1
id__ | name__ | data_
---------------------
1____| name1__| data1
2____| name2__| data2
3____| name3__| data3
4____| name4__| data4

Table2
id__ | table1_id_| user_id
---------------------------
1____| ____3_____| ___3___
2____| ____2_____| ___3___
3____| ____2_____| ___1___
4____| ____3_____| ___1___
```

I want to get 'name' and 'data' from table1 except ids from table2 that belongs to users.id = 3, that means i need to get this:
Table result (all fields from table1) (result for user_id = 3) (btw for user_id = 1 result must be the same):

Desired output:

```
id__| name__ | data_
--------------------
1___| name1__| data1
4___| name4__| data4
---------------------
```

What the SQL query i should use?

Comment: What SQL have you tried? Which bits didn't work? What part can you manage by yourself, and where did you get stuck when trying to extend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table2 WHERE user_id = 3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what i need.

Comment: @omnomah Glad to help you. Could you accept the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although you can solve this using `NOT IN`, I recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_2 t2
                  WHERE t2.table1_id = t1.id AND t2.user_id = 3
                 );
```

Why?  `NOT IN` behaves rather strangely if *any* `table1_id` value is `NULL`.  If that occurs, then the `NOT IN` only returns false and `NULL` -- it *never* returns true.  Hence, no rows at all will be returned if even one column value is `NULL`.

`NOT EXISTS`, on the other hand, behaves more intuitively, so you don't have to worry about this condition.